# How to pass loop variable from loop into conroller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok probably there is easy way to do this but I really can't figure it out. In view I have each loop and logic that shouldn't be there. Problem is that I don't know how to pass loop variable inside method.

```
 - @groups.in_groups_of(2, false).each do |groups|
  .row
   -groups.each do |group|
    .box.col-md-5{id: "group_#{group.id}"}
      %h3= group.group_name          
      - if UserGroup.where("group_id = ? AND user_id = ?", group.id, current_user.id).exists?
        %p= link_to 'Show', group
        - if current_user[:id] != group.created_by
```

Lastly I want to ask if there is any need to move this into method or helper?

```
- if current_user[:id] != group.created_by
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that you have these lines in your user model

```
class User
  has_many :user_groups
end
```

now in the controller, you write:

```
@user_group_ids = current_user.user_groups.pluck(:group_id)
```

This will avoid having [N+1 queries](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/)

Now in your view

```
 - @groups.in_groups_of(2, false).each do |groups|
  .row
   -groups.each do |group|
    .box.col-md-5{id: "group_#{group.id}"}
      %h3= group.group_name          
      - if @user_group_ids.include?(group.id)
        %p= link_to 'Show', group
        - if current_user[:id] != group.created_by
```

Now as for the current_user[:id] != group.created_by doesn't need to move anywhere unless it is something you use a lot. This is the general rule, if you use it in more than 2 places, put it where you can reuse it.